# Facebook Post-to-Wall PHP Script - Post as Page?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to post to a Facebook page for my site using an automated PHP script. However, I came across a problem - the script will post as the user logged in on that computer. I want the script to post to the wall as the page entity.

The previous questions on this site don't really help me, as I'm pretty new at this and have no idea how to manage things such as permissions and such (so just telling me to add "X permission" doesn't really help me...as I have no idea WHERE to even add said line[s] of code!) Facebook's documentation is hard to navigate, with most Google Answers tutorials involving previous versions of the Facebook API). My code has pretty much been copy-pasted from the tutorials I have come across.

How do I allow the PHP script to post to the page AS the page?

Comment: I suggest you to first learn the basics i.e. requiring permissions and getting access_tokens with the SDK of your choice, as you will need them both for this task, and then try to do these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

Learn basics i.e. requiring permissions and getting access_tokens from

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/